# Node js: Download file to memory and pass to library function without saving to disk

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf-extraction

The below code is working fine, but I had some code feedback:
"Why download and save the file to disk, only to read it back in memory?"

However, after spending some hours exploring options with `Buffer` and `stream`, I just don't seem to be getting anywhere.

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const { PdfData } = require('pdfdataextract');
const axios = require('axios').default;

const getPDFText = async ({ url }) => {
  const tmpDir = `${process.cwd()}/my_dir`;
  const writer = fs.createWriteStream(`${tmpDir}/document.pdf`);
  const response = await axios({
    url,
    method: 'get',
    responseType: 'stream'
  });
  response.data.pipe(writer);

  const text = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writer.on('finish', () => {
      const fileData = fs.readFileSync(`${tmpDir}/document.pdf`);

      PdfData.extract(fileData, {
        get: {
           // ...
        },
      })
      .then(resolve)
      .catch(reject);
    });
    writer.on('error', reject);
  });

  return text;
};
```

How can I avoid saving the file to disk, and to instead feed it into the `PdfData.extract` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The signature for `.extract`](https://github.com/lublak/pdfdataextract/blob/main/src/pdfdata.ts#L158-L165) says it accepts an `Uint8Array`.

Something like

```
const {PdfData} = require('pdfdataextract');
const axios = require('axios').default;

async function getPDFText({url}) {
  const response = await axios({
    url,
    method: 'get',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  });
  const pdfUint8Array = new Uint8Array(response.data);
  const res = await PdfData.extract(pdfUint8Array, /* ... */);
  console.log(res);
  return res;
}
```

could do the trick?